# Why is that a security problem in sonarqube?

Tags: java, security, sonarqube, zip

i have the following method:

```
    public List<String> getZipFileList(String fullPath) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("====> ZipService: getZipFileList <====");
        List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    
        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fullPath)) {
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
            while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                String fileName = ((ZipEntry) zipEntries.nextElement()).getName();
                fileList.add(fileName);
            }
        }
    
        return fileList;
    }
```

In the line with the Enumeration say Sonarqube the following message:

> Make sure that expanding this archive file is safe here.

Why is that not safe and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Extracting zip is insecure due to zip bomb problem or say the zip may contain files not secure enough to extract

refer https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS04-J.+Safely+extract+files+from+ZipInputStream   for valid code

Comment: Thank you, the example from the link was very helpful.